# how to navigate between two pages in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic framework.I dont know how to navigate between two pages.I was trying to create a login page using ionic using side menu template.Here goes the code for login.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Login">
<ion-header-bar>
<h1 class="title">Login</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
<form ng-submit="doLogin()">
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email or Phone">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
    </label>
    <label class="item">
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
    </label>
    <label class="item">
    <span class="input-label">New user?</span>
    <a class="button ion-plus-round" href="#/app/signup">Signup</a>    
    </label>

  </div>
</form>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

In app.js :-

```
.state('app.login', {
    url: "/login",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

I put the login button in menu.html like this rest all being same

```
 <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/login">
          Login
        </ion-item>
```

Login button is working when i click in menu but Signup button is not working in login page.Can u help me?I am new to ionic and angularjs

Comment: try `ng-href="#/app/signup"` instead of `href="#/app/signup"` and check the structure of you sign up page too. make sure that you are not missing any  `<ion-view>` or `<ion-content>` tags or closing them.

Comment: try changing your url of the state to be the same as href `url: 'app/signup'`

Comment: changing url did not work

Comment: This issue is resolved or not?

Comment: This is resolved thankyou Vinesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help,

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="loginView">
<ion-header-bar>
<h1 class="title">Login</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
<form ng-submit="doLogin()">
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email or Phone">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
    </label>
    <label class="item">
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
    </label>
    <label class="item">
    <span class="input-label">New user?</span>
    <a class="button ion-plus-round" ui-sref="app.signup">Signup</a>    
    </label>

  </div>
</form>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

your routing should be,

```
.state('app.login', {
    url: "/login",
    views: {
      'loginView': {
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    views: {
      'signupView': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

your login button,

```
 <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="app.login">
          Login
        </ion-item>
```

UI-Router is used by AngularJS and Ionic. So consider using `ui-sref` attribute.
This  has one more advantage, oviously your parent state remains bound to 'app' when you use say for example, `ui-sref="app.login"`. Do not use `href` when dealing with Angular. You have an Angular option for that, which is `ng-href`.

add `<ion-view view-title="Signup" name="signupView">` for signUp page

hope this helps

Comment: Where should i keep loginView or signupView?

Comment: add ` <ion-view view-title="Login" name="loginView">` in login page and ` <ion-view view-title="Login" name="signupView">` for signUp page.. hope this helps. I recomend, have a look at this http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/CbBsA too. You can follow the approach mentioned there.

Comment: I mean, change  `<ion-view view-title="Login" name="loginView">` in login page and `<ion-view view-title="Login" name="signupView">` for signUp page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove attribute "href" and add **ui-sref="app.signup"**...
Hopefully it'll resolve issue.

Also in routing configuration, change views object name "menuContent" for singup.

```
.state('app.login', {
    url: "/login",
    views: {
      'menuLogin': {
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    views: {
      'menuSingup': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Where should i keep menuLogin or menuSignup views?

Comment: Where should i put menuSignup or menu Login views?